# QPrintDialog::exec() error on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, printing

I'm trying to use QtPrintSupport on Windows.

```
bool SomeClass::print()
{
    QPrinter printer;
    QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, this);
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Rejected)
        return false;

    edit->print(&printer);
    return true;
}
```

In Debug mode all works fine. But in Release `QPrintDialog::exec()` returns QDialog::Rejected immediately.

Qt version : 5.0

I added folder "printsupport" to myApp.exe file path. `QPrintDialog::exec()` work correctly. But after calling `edit->print(&printer)` programm exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Qt libraries to version 5.1. Print support is fully working.